# Get Distinct Values Based on a Second Column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, distinct

My table looks like this:

[image]

and I am trying to get distinct values of `repunit`, based on a second column in teradata like this:

[image]

by running this query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT foo."repunit", 
    COALESCE(foo."country",'NO-COUNTRY') 
    FROM db.table AS foo
```

It does not work as expected, I am getting quite some `NULL`s as results and none `NO-COUNTRY`.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT belongs to SELECT. I.e. I'd put `SELECT DISTINCT` as first row.

Comment: However, no need for SELECT DISTINCT here, do a GROUP BY instead.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `GROUP BY` to get one row for each repunit value. Use `MAX()` (or `MIN()`), to pick a non-null value. Use `COALESCE()` to return NO-COUNTRY if no country found.

```
SELECT 
    foo."repunit", 
    COALESCE(MAX(foo."country"),'NO-COUNTRY') 
FROM db.table AS foo
GROUP BY foo."repunit"
```

If there also are blank values representing NO-VALUE:

```
SELECT 
    foo."repunit", 
    case when MAX(foo."country") <> ' ' then MAX(foo."country")
         else 'NO-COUNTRY'
    end  
FROM db.table AS foo
GROUP BY foo."repunit"
```

Comment: It works, **but** I am receiving a lot of "blanks" on the `foo."country"` column. These are not `NULL`, but still not ok. Any idea how to avoid these?

Comment: Do you have "blank" values too in the country column?

Comment: Yup. Quite a lot of them.

Comment: Or shorter, but a bit harder to understand: `COALESCE(NULLIF(MAX(foo."country"),''),'NO-COUNTRY')`

Comment: @dnoeth, for some unknown reason I never use NULLIF.

Comment: In fact, you will never see NULLIF/COALESCE in a Teradata Explain, it's always rewritten to a *searched case* like yours :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, of course, same code underneath. Build up the parse tree and then traverse it.